# automatically restart nginx proxy with monit

Tags: proxy, nginx, monit

I tried to mointor my nginx proxy in one VM with this config in

```
# cat /etc/monit/conf.d/nginx 
check process nginx with pidfile /run/nginx.pid
    start program = "/usr/sbin/service nginx start" with timeout 60 seconds
    stop program  = "/usr/sbin/service nginx stop"
    if failed host somedomain_here.org port 443 protocol http for 3 cycles then restart
```

But I only get these errors in /var/log/monit.log

```
error    : 'nginx' failed protocol test [HTTP] at [somedomain_here.org]:443 [TCP/IP] -- Connection refused
```

although the domain has https. it seems like the proxy itself cannot access the sites that it proxies to other vms on the same host.

How can I monitor nginx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for the pid if nginx is still running with this config in `/etc/monit/conf.d/nginx` instead:

```
check process nginx with pidfile /var/run/nginx.pid
    start program = "/etc/init.d/nginx start"
    stop program = "/etc/init.d/nginx stop"
```